# Playwright: Simulating Ctrl+Shift+M for Toggling Device Toolbar in CDP not working

Tags: javascript, simulation, playwright, devtools

I'm trying to simulate mobile page rendering and testing in Chrome using Playwright. I need to activate the Toggle Device Toolbar via the Ctrl+Shift+M keyboard shortcut within the DevTools panel.

Here's my code:

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true // enable developer tools
  });

  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  
  // create cdp session
  const client = await context.newCDPSession(page);

  // activate devtools
  await client.send('Page.enable');
  await client.send('Page.bringToFront');
  await client.send('Page.navigate', { url: 'Some url' });
  
  // get devTools targetId
  const targets = await client.send('Target.getTargets', {});
  const devToolsTargetId = targets.targetInfos.find((info) => info.type === 'other').targetId;
  
  // focus on devtools panel
  // await client.send('Target.activateTarget', { targetId: devToolsTargetId });
  await client.send('Target.attachToTarget', { targetId: devToolsTargetId });

  // simulate shortcuts: Ctrl + Shift + M
  await client.send('Input.dispatchKeyEvent', {
    type: 'keyDown',
    modifiers: 8, // means 'Ctrl+Shift'
    windowsVirtualKeyCode: 77, // means key 'M'
    nativeVirtualKeyCode: 77,
    autoRepeat: false,
    isKeypad: false,
    targetId: devToolsTargetId,
  });
  await client.send('Input.dispatchKeyEvent', {
    type: 'keyUp',
    modifiers: 8,
    windowsVirtualKeyCode: 77,
    nativeVirtualKeyCode: 77,
    autoRepeat: false,
    isKeypad: false,
    targetId: devToolsTargetId,
  });

  // Do something on the page, e.g., take a screenshot
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });

  // await browser.close();
})();
```

This code opens Chrome with DevTools, navigates to a URL, attempts to focus on the DevTools panel with 'Target.attachToTarget', and sends the simulated key events for 'Ctrl+Shift+M' with 'Input.dispatchKeyEvent'. However, the Toolbar doesn't get activated.

The output of 'targets.targetInfos' is:

```
[
  {
    targetId: 'CBF44E36684FD28034D2543C684754A5',
    type: 'other',
    title: '',
    url: 'devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@f4095e9665f7d7a2531edefcea119d45d899d95b/&can_dock=true&targetType=tab',
    attached: true,
    canAccessOpener: false,
    browserContextId: '91C311D78E340D26C7A07F56F6EE4198'
  },
  {
    targetId: '214735BD67A2224755912F57CDBF353E',
    type: 'page',
    title: 'about:blank',
    url: 'Some url',
    attached: true,
    canAccessOpener: false,
    browserContextId: '68E0C79153C5A7951F11E74D4482AE57'
  }
]
```

My question is: why isn't the Toggle Device Toolbar activating when I simulate the Ctrl+Shift+M shortcut in the DevTools panel? How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried [emulation](https://playwright.dev/docs/emulation)?